# Why avoid string module and use str in Python?

Tags: python

What are the reasons why one should avoid the string module and use str instead  in Python? Anybody knows? Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: [Deprecated](https://www.quantifiedcode.com/knowledge-base/correctness/Avoid%20deprecated%20string%20functions/4by9Hhj4), and there is no reason to use something like `string.capitalize("word")` when you can just do `"word".capitalize()`. Unless, of course, using the `string` module caters to a specific need.

Comment: Where did you see this advice?

Answer (score 2):

There is a bunch of deprecated functions in the `string` module clearly tagged as such in Python2 (https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/string.html#deprecated-string-functions). These function are unavailable in Python3. Obviously, these functions should not be used. Let's now talk  about the rest.

The existence of deprecated functions does not mean that the whole `string` library module is to be avoided in any way.

Further, you don't have a real choice between `str` class and `string` module. Take for example the functionality of `Template` and Formatter. The former provides "$name" substitution and the latter allows to parse format strings and to customize string formatting. These are uncommon tasks, but if you need to do just that, the `str` class alone does not provide the right tools.

Comment: I tried 'import string' in Pythn 3.5 and it worked, appears not deprecated.

Comment: @DjangoUrl, VPfB isn't saying the entire _module_ is deprecated. "The existence of deprecated functions does not mean that the whole `string` library module is to be avoided in any way." Some of the functions _in_ the module are, e.g. `atof()`, `atoi()`, `atol()`.